# Google Maps Autocomplete removing address

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

We are using the `Google Maps` `autocomplete` feature on our website but have noticed that it occasionally removes the numeric portion of an address for valid addresses.  For example this address:

> 5732 Mountain Front Avenue, Billings, Montana 59106

You can see this on `maps.google.com` if you enter the above address and click on search.  In the results area the `5732` is stripped off, which is what it did in our application.  Same results for these addresses:

> 492 Snowberry Ln  Harrisonburg VA 22801
>
> 59 Meheu Circle Kahului, Hawaii 96732

There is a similar thread here from 2015 but it has not been updated.  Any news or known workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

All of the addresses you mentioned are not currently in the maps data. The street for those addresses is indeed in the maps data, but not all of the street numbers that reside on the street. If you try to enter the address on maps.google.com, you will see a link in the results drowpdown that says "Add a missing places to Google Maps." You can click this link to add the new place. Alternatively, you can go to maps.google.com and then click the hamburger menu in the top-left of the page, and select "add a missing place." You can also add a new places programatically using the places API as described here:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place

Please note that when using the place add method above, the new place is available immediately in Nearby Searches initiated by your application. The new place also enters a moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added place does not appear in Text Search or Radar Search results, or to other applications, until it has been approved by the moderation process.

After review and moderation you will be able to query the new places you add to the maps data.

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).